# How to find all code depending on a jar in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependency-management

In JetBrains's .NET world I can use ["Find Code Dependent on Module"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Finding_Code_Dependent_on_Modules.html) in ReSharper or ["Find Dependent Code"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Finding_Code_Dependent_on_Modules.html) in Rider to easily find all usages of a library (likely excluding reflective uses, for obvious reasons).

What is the equivalent in IntelliJ and the Java world?

I have tried expanding the external library under the *External Libraries* section of the *Project* window, right-clicking the *.jar entry and choosing **"Find Usages"**, but no results are ever found even with really simple cases.

Comment: Remove it and see where compilation fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is not currently implemented. Feature request [`IDEA-51267`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-51267) hopes to implement this feature.

However, you can expand the jar file and select packages inside of it. Then choose `Find Usages:`
[image: Expanded jar file, with find usages highlighted]

By default, the dependencies are grouped by usage type; however, this may include internal usages of the classes. To prevent this, click `Group by Usage Type`. This lists all of the usages sorted by module.

Comment: +1 for a well researched and written answer!  This will have to do, but it has the notable difference that it looks for the usage of the package name.   If the same package name appears in multiple jars it will show usages from any of the contributing jars.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an official way of doing it using Intellij's dependency analysis. You just need to go under Code > Analyze Code > Dependencies. Then you'll be able to see where every dependency was used including which part of it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies-analysis.html